# In jqGrid data is not binding, showing blank grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: 'SampleController/jqGrid1',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Mobile', 'Email', 'City', 'State', 'Gender'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 100 },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100 },
                { name: 'Mobile', index: 'Mobile', width: 100 },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 100 },
                { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 100 },
                 { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 100 },
                { name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', width: 100 }
            ],
            sortname: 'Id',
            rowNum: 10,
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'List of Students',
            scrollOffset: 0,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode:true
        });

    });
```

controller code:

```
    public JsonResult jqGrid1()
    {
         return Json(objDB.SelectALL(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`objDB.SelectAll()` returns a List 
is there any mistake Please inform. When i debug the code it is not calling the method `jqGrid1()` of sample controller.

Comment: url: 'SampleController/jqGrid1', its should be url: 'Sample/jqGrid1',

Comment: still its not working.I put 'Sample/jqGrid1'

Comment: Use `url: '@Url.Action("jqGrid1","Sample")'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
url: 'SampleController/jqGrid1',
```

To

```
url: '/Sample/jqGrid1',
```

OR
Use the Url.Action helper method to generate the correct relative url to the action method.

```
url: '@Url.Action("jqGrid1","Sample")',
```

When razor executes the code for your view, it will run the Url.Action method and output the correct URL(which will have the controller name if needed).

**Edit:**
*As per comment jqGrid data is not binding, showing blank grid*
You have to return the JSON data in the proper format with the necessary parameters.

For ex.

```
return Json(new{
                 total = 1,
                 page = 1,
                 records = yourCount, // actual data count
                 rows = objDB.SelectALL()// actual data
              });
```

Comment: ,well its calling the jqGrid1() ,but still data is not binding to GridView.